# How to get the total count from the images table using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

i am new to using msql and i want to get the count from the plan table that belong to particular team_id

Below are the two tables named purhasedplan and the images table

[image]

i want to write a msql query that would return the sum of count for team_id 2
so the expected output is 15

i have tried below

'SELECT plan FROM purchasedplan WHERE  team= 2',

this for some reason selects only the first one

so only the first row
id   team_id   count  name
4     2         5     first

i want it to select two of the them and give the sum of count.

so the final output is 15 i just want to see the sum of counts for team_id = 2

how can i do it. could someone help me with this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select sum(count) cnt
from plan
where team_id = 2
```

If you want one row per team, with their total count:

```
select team_id, sum(count) cnt
from plan
group by team_id
```